# How to get weekly count in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the count by each week from a table to show Weekly report, which shows the total per week number (Week 1, Week 2 .... Week54).

This is my SQL:

```
 select DATEPART(week, CAST([submissionDate] as date)) as [weeks],sum(qty) 
 as [Zen Usage] FROM [zicucfbu_MIS].[dbo].[FileUploadDetails] where [route] 
 like 'ZENIT_WS%' and DATEPART(week, CAST([submissionDate] as date)) = 
 DATEPART(week, cast(GETDATE() as date))  
 and year(CAST([submissionDate] as date)) = year(cast(GETDATE() as date))
 group by DATEPART(week, CAST([submissionDate] as date))  order by weeks
```

But with this SQL I'm only getting the current week total count. I  would appreciate most if anyone could help me to show the total count by each week.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause has a condition that explicitly limits the results to the current week:

```
DATEPART(week, CAST([submissionDate] as date)) = 
DATEPART(week, cast(GETDATE() as date))
```

Just remove it and you should be fine.